# How do I use PCA to know if two categories are sources of variability?

Tags: pca, variability

I have a matrix of values 10000x2 that fall in two categories A and B. I would like to use PCA to know if the categories are large sources of variability. 
I ran a PCA analysis in R, but I have no idea how to make sense of the numbers I got nor how to work out what it means for my two categories.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Variability in what? Are you saying that your response variable Y is a 10Kx2 matrix and that you have 1 covariate X that is binary? Do you have a binary outcome that you want to explain using your matrix? Is 1 of the columns of your matrix a binary indicator?

Answer (score 1):

I read this as: I have 10000 observations, 2 numeric variables (let's call them $X$ and $Y$) and also a categorical variable with categories A and B.

I wouldn't start with PCA or even use it here: just plot your two variables on a scatter plot of $Y$ versus $X$ and distinguish As from Bs.

If the pattern is really messy, then plotting As with all as backdrop and Bs with all as backdrop might help. [This thread gives examples](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/270264-subsetplot-available-on-ssc). [This one gives more references to literature.](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1320504-graphing-over-time-trajectories-without-excluding-cases-that-have-only-a-single-data-point)

Comment: +1. It's a pity that there is no answer of yours here on CV demonstrating your *Graphing subsets* approach and giving examples/references.

Comment: @amoeba Thanks very much. Come the right question, and it will be an answer. (I once gave a talk mentioning it, and someone said "I liked your nice example of X's approach", mentioning an author. I pointed out that I published before X (!)  but in turn have re-discovered, as usual, that I was at best remembering something I'd seen earlier.)